# Jmeter Login Request with cookies have wrong Response

Tags: jmeter

I m new in jmeter i want to know if i send post request for login with cookies then in Response below information is displaying .

> Request Error We’re sorry, there was a problem with your request.
>   Please make sure you have cookies enabled and try again.

What could be going wrong.?

[image]

Comment: How did you record your script for Linkedin Login? I have just tried it (using blazemeter plugin) and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: i record it through jmeter recording controller ....

Answer (score 0):

It may be not about the missing or incorrect cookies.

You need to provide valid `loginCsrfParam` value as well, it needs to be extracted from previous response via one of the following PostProcessors:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)

converted into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and used as a parameter in your login request.

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for comprehensive information on bypassing CSRF protection in your JMeter test.